# OpenMap - 5m Countour Lines - Paris

Tags: gis, contour, openmaptiles

apologies if this question has been answered already - from the similar questions list it doesn't look exactly like it has.

I am looking for 5 metre contour lines, for the Paris area, to use in ArcGIS i.e. as a shapefile. It looks like this might be available through OpenMap Tiles but I am unsure, and before making the purchase (it said $13), any confirmation of the product would be much appreciated.

I have read about using data from STRM to create these contours but that is beyond me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save $13 you could use ogr2ogr to convert a pbf to a shapefile.
https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

But you need to keep the input and output under 2GB.  I would suggest downloading only the Ile-de-France subregion from GeoFabrik 
http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france/ile-de-france.html